# What are those functions

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

what are such functions $$f(x) = \int_{c}^{x} R \left(t, (P(t))^{\frac{1}{n}} \right) \, dt,$$
where $R$ is a rational function of its two arguments, P is a polynomial  with no repeated roots, $n \geq 3$and $c$ is a constant.Any research on such a kind of function?And what is the inverse function of $f(x)$?Since we know $n=2$,it is elliptic integral,and it's inverse function is elliptic function.

Comment: XL_at_China's functions.

Comment: @metacompactness,you are kidding.

Comment: If they don't have a name and you give them an extensive study, why can't you name them with your last name?

Comment: @metacompactness,I have been repeatedly inventing ideas and formulas which had been completed long ago,:(

Comment: I suggest you to add clearly to the question: `Do such functions already have a name?` if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

It's a special case of an (incomplete) [Abelian integral](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_integral). Namely, we have the integral $$\int_c^x R(t,y)_{f=0}\, dt$$ where we require that $(y,t)$ lie on the algebraic curve $f(t,y)=y^n-P(t)=0$.

Comment: Thank you,Semiclassical,I have been repeatedly inventing ideas and formulas which had been completed long ago,:(